# Using a while() statement inside a variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I've been trying to generate a Google chart using the YouTube API by placing the data from a table directly into a Google line chart. But found myself in a dilema after not being able to use a while(); statement inside the variable.

The current function to generate the chart is as shows

```
 function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Day', 'Views', 'Subscribers'],
      ['2008',  1530,      540],
    ]);

    console.log(data);

    var options = {
      title: 'Channel Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

When I try to put in the while() statement it looks like this:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Day', 'Views', 'Subscribers'],
      while (mywhilestatement) { dosomething }
      ['2008',  1530,      540],
    ]);
```

But when I try to insert my while() statement it breaks and returns an invalid token error:

```
var eqno = 1;
    var day = $(".danalytics tr").eq(eqno).children().eq(0).text();
    var views = parseInt($(".danalytics tr").eq(eqno).children().eq(1).text());
    var subs = parseInt($(".danalytics tr").eq(eqno).children().eq(2).text());

  while (eqno < rowcount) {
    "['" + $(".danalytics tr").eq(eqno).children().eq(0).text() + "', " + parseInt($(".danalytics tr").eq(eqno).children().eq(1).text()) + ", " + parseInt($(".danalytics tr").eq(eqno).children().eq(2).text()) + "],";
    eqno++;
  }
```

I know the while statement is valid because i've tried console logging the response.

How can I resolve the issue of not being able to get the data into the chart in this method, what bypass could I use or is there a different (proper) method to doing it that i'm missing?

The original data to go into the table comes from a file_get_contents request to an API which returns JSON data back.

Comment: a `while()` is valid in the console. It's valid as a chunk of code. It's *not* valid in the middle of an array. Even if it *were*, it would require a comma afterwards, to separate it from the following element in the array.

Comment: Enclose your while functionality in a function or closure and use the result from that. While loops are not valid parameters by themselves.

Comment: Can you explain with an answer @mopsyd? I don't know another way how to do it. I know a while isn't valid in the middle, I don't know a way around the issue i'm having which is why I asked this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should construct your array BEFORE you pass it to arrayToDataTable();
I mean something like this:

```
var dataArray = [
    ['Day', 'Views', 'Subscribers']
];


var eqno = 1;

while (eqno < rowcount) {
    var day = $(".danalytics tr").eq(eqno).children().eq(0).text();
    var views = parseInt($(".danalytics tr").eq(eqno).children().eq(1).text());
    var subs = parseInt($(".danalytics tr").eq(eqno).children().eq(2).text());

    dataArray.push([day, views, subs]);
    eqno++;
}

dataArray.push(['2008',  1530,      540]);

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
...
```

In the original post the code in the while(){} constructs an array-like string. It looks nice in the console but you need an actual JS array to pass as a parameter.

Comment: Wow! Great explanation on how it looks pretty put isn't an array, I understand it much better now. +1 !